# Error 404 on page reload with angular routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm getting error 404 when realoading page. This happening after user loaded new template in ng-view (redirected from routing).
This is how routing configured.

```
config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/templates/home.html',
                controller: 'smu72Controller'
            })
            .when('/objects', {
                templateUrl: '/templates/objects.html',
                controller: 'smu72Controller'
            })
            .when('/object/:Id', {
                templateUrl: '/templates/object.html',
                controller: 'smu72Controller'
            })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
```

Comment: on which template you're seeing this?

Comment: Anyone, except home ("/").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by rewriting url in Global.asax as follow:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string url = Request.Url.LocalPath;
            if (!url.Contains("api") && !System.IO.File.Exists(Context.Server.MapPath(url)))
                Context.RewritePath(ROOT_DOCUMENT);
    }
```